# Why cannot I access the type field when using Collectors.toMap?

Tags: java, list, dictionary, lambda, java-stream

why cannot I access the `id` property of `Device` ?

```
final List<Device> devicesList = jsonFileHandlerDevice.getList();

ConcurrentMap<Integer, Device> map =
        devicesList.stream()
                   .collect(Collectors.toMap(item -> item.id, item -> item));
```

where

```
public class Device {

    public MobileOs mobileOs;
    public Integer id;


    public Device() {
    }

    public Device(MobileOs mobileOs, double osVersion, int allocatedPort, Integer id, String uuid) {
        this.mobileOs = mobileOs;
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

see here:

[image]

Comment: I think perhaps you got a misleading error message. I believe the actual error is using a `ConcurrentMap<Integer, Device>` type when the type returned by the collector is `Map<Integer, Device>`. If you want the returned `Map` to be a `ConcurrentMap`, you must use the `toMap` variant that accepts a supplier (which determines the type of the Map to be returned).

Comment: see my added screenshot

Comment: What is the error message ?

Comment: I just cannot access the member "id"

Comment: @EladBenda That could be a bug of your IDE. Try to change the type of `map` to `Map` and see if the error goes away.

Comment: you're right. please add an answer and I mark it.

Comment: is there an easy way to construct a cuncurrentMap from map then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got a misleading error message. The actual error is using a `ConcurrentMap<Integer, Device>` type when the type returned by the collector is `Map<Integer, Device>`.

If you want the returned `Map` to be a `ConcurrentMap`, you can use the `toMap` variant that accepts a supplier (which determines the type of the `Map` to be returned).

Something like this should work :

```
ConcurrentMap<Integer, Device> map =
        devicesList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(item -> item.id,
                                          item -> item,
                                          (item1,item2)->item2,
                                          ConcurrentHashMap::new));
```

or as Alexis commented, just use `Collector.toConcurrentMap`.

Comment: _"you must use the toMap variant"_ ... or simply use `Collectors.toConcurrentMap`.

Comment: @AlexisC.I wasn't aware of that. It didn't occur to me the API may contain such a collector. Thanks :)